# Securely Use Random Number Generator for Lottery Winning

Tags: random

I want to design a lottery winning mechanism using random number generator. I know that for computer, there is no true randomness but only "pseudorandom". If the system gets hacked and random seed is seen, people will know the sequence of random numbers. In fact, there is news that people did this and won several lotteries. I am thinking about two ways of designing my system:

1. Use random number generator as a global variable. There is only one
   random seed; the sequence is generated when the system starts.

   Con:

   a. Once the random seed is seen, hackers will know the sequence
   easily.

   b. Once the system crashes and restarts, the sequence will repeat
   itself.
2. Create a random number generator using timestamp as random seed each
   time to generate a number.

   Con:

   a. Obviously timestamp cannot be directly used. There are some
   tricks needed to be done with the timestamp each time. For example,
   plus or minus some values each time on the timestamp. What algorithm can I use here to do this kind of modification on timestamp?

   b. Is this method even taking advantage of random number generator?
   It seems I am just creating a random number by myself...

As we can see, either of the method above is not secure enough. Which way is slightly better? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you seen this? https://www.random.org/randomness/

Answer (score 0):

The notion that computers are incapable of truly random numbers hasn't been true for decades. All modern desktop and laptop computers have true hardware-based random number generators. Even most small embedded systems do as well.

That said, it may be the case that your programming language hasn't caught up to the recent hardware, or that even if it has, it's easy to make a mistake with RNGs and get a bad result from a good generator. So it's probably a good idea to use something like random.org unless you know what you're doing.